# Remove columns + keep certain rows in multiple large .csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

Hello I'm really new here as well as in the world of python.

I have some (~1000) .csv files, including ~ 1800000 rows of information each. The files are in the following form:

```
5302730,131841,-0.29999999999999999,NULL,2013-12-31 22:00:46.773
5303072,188420,28.199999999999999,NULL,2013-12-31 22:27:46.863
5350066,131841,0.29999999999999999,NULL,2014-01-01 00:37:21.023
5385220,-268368577,4.5,NULL,2014-01-01 03:12:14.163
5305752,-268368587,5.1900000000000004,NULL,2014-01-01 03:11:55.207
```

So, i would like for all of the files:
(1) to remove the 4th (NULL) column
(2) to keep in every file only certain rows (depending on the value of the first column i.e.5302730, keep only the rows that containing that value)

I don't know if this is even possible, so any answer is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all the columns for the 4th going to be null, if so you can do a find and replace.

Comment: I'd use pandas for this. Pandas will load each csv file as a table like object. U can then drop a column. Then logical operators to select rows based in col 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html)

One can use the `csv.reader` function to generate an iterator of lines, with each lines cells as a list.

```
for line in csv.reader(open("filename.csv")):
    # Remove 4th column, remember python starts counting at 0
    line = line[:3] + line[4:]
    if line[0] == "thevalueforthefirstcolumn":
         dosomethingwith(line)
```

Comment: So, i got a new file without the 4th column using this:

import csv

with open('20140101.csv', "r") as file_in:
    with open('test.csv', "w") as file_out:

        writer = csv.writer(file_out)

        for line in csv.reader(file_in):
            line = line[:3] + line[4:]
            writer.writerow(line)

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. So, i got a new file without the 4th column using this:

<code>import csv

with open('original20140101.csv', "r") as file_in:
    with open('20140101.csv', "w") as file_out:

        writer = csv.writer(file_out)

        for line in csv.reader(file_in):
            line = line[:3] + line[4:]
            writer.writerow(line)</code>

If 20140101 refers to the 01-01-2015 (date), and all my files have this format, how i can make the loop changing files (input + output)?

Comment: You could use a for loop over dates, and use `infile="original{}.csv".format(date)` and `outfile = "{}.csv".format(date)`

Comment: Thanks i made it! Thanks again!

Comment: @pangeras, please mark this answer as accepted if it contains the answer you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this sort of operation with CSV files more than once and want to use different parameters regarding column to skip, column to use as key and what to filter on, you can use something like this:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename, column_to_skip=None, key_column=0, key_filter=None):

    data_from_csv = []

    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for row in csv_reader:

            # Skip data in specific column
            if column_to_skip is not None:
                del row[column_to_skip]

            # Filter out rows where the key doesn't match
            if key_filter is not None:
                key = row[key_column]
                if key_filter != key:
                    continue

            data_from_csv.append(row)

    return data_from_csv

def write_csv(filename, data_to_write):

    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        for row in data_to_write:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

data = read_csv('data.csv', column_to_skip=3, key_filter='5302730')
write_csv('data2.csv', data)
```